# How can I rearrange the output of a query based on the order of another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following query I'm working on/building for my work (located in the 'Query Result' sheet of my example link).

```
=QUERY({'1st'!A7:D;'2nd'!A7:D}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) GROUP BY Col1")
```

It's doing the calculation just as I intended, but I need it in the sort order shown in the "Master Chart" sheet. I've tried to use ORDER BY, but since I'm using GROUP BY with aggregation functions, it's not functioning how I expect.

Can someone show me the best way to get the same result that the query is giving but in my desired order?

A simplified copy of my sheet is located [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmfV59hfWcCYOlWQmdjRKcKhNl1hj9O_1IaZrGm6fAY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({QUERY({'1st'!A7:D;'2nd'!A7:D}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) '', SUM(Col3) '', SUM(Col4) ''"),SORT(FILTER(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE({'1st'!A7:A;'2nd'!A7:A}), {'Master Chart'!A2:A,'Master Chart'!E2:E},{1,2}, FALSE), UNIQUE({'1st'!A7:A;'2nd'!A7:A})<>""),1,TRUE)},6,TRUE),COUNTA(UNIQUE({'1st'!A7:A;'2nd'!A7:A})),4)
```

### Explanation

This query is composed of two main parts, wrapped in `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(...))`.

Part A is `QUERY(...)` which does much the same thing as you already had, although I took the liberty of not including results where Col1 (tire size) is null, and I also removed automatically generated "sum" labels that `=QUERY` creates.

Part B is `SORT(FILTER(VLOOKUP(...)))`, which sorts each row in `Master Chart` by the same order that the `QUERY` does. This then provides a `Sort Order` value (from `Master Sheet`) for each row returned by the `QUERY`.

The outermost `SORT` takes the results from Part A and sorts them using the `Sort Order` from Part B. Finally, the `=ARRAYCONSTRAIN` gets rid of the excess—Part B is only used for sorting and should not be shown in the final result.

If you wish to have the "sum" labels, you could add them back manually by enclosing the entire formula in the following:

```
={{"","sum","sum","sum"}; FORMULA HERE }
```

If you wish to count null results from Col1, this method will not work as you have not provided a distinct `Sort Order` for null results.

Functions used:

- [=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en)
- [=SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [=QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [=FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [=VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [=UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)
- [=COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en)

Comment: This is incredible and very educational. My full-size sheet has 31 sheets (one for every day) and over 1000 tire sizes so the query is hilariously massive, but works. Thank you so much! When I wake up I'll try to add more context to my question so people in the future may follow this solution more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vlookup()` to only show the rows in the results of `query()` where the size matches the list in `Master Chart`, in the same order, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      'Master Chart'!A2:A, 
      query( 
        { '1st'!A7:D;'2nd'!A7:D }, 
        "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4) 
         group by Col1", 
        0 
      ), 
      { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```